# How to swap elements in file in C

Tags: c

How can i swap elements in file?  If the file contents are:

```
AB CD EF GH
aa bb cc dd ee 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

If I want to swap the elements of column 2 with 3. The output of file should be:

```
AB CD EF GH
aa bb cc dd ee 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
AB EF CD GH
aa cc bb dd ee
1 3 2 4 5 6 7
```

How can i do this using `C`?

Comment: And what have you done so far ?

Comment: You can achieve this using file I/O in conjunction with strtok and some conditional logic.

Comment: Why would you want to do this with C?

Comment: I want to know the method how to do it using C. Also I want to know the libraries that I can use.

Comment: There is no `method` in C ;)

Comment: You have to open a file then read it's line swap the elements then write it to a file for each row in the file.

Comment: You didn't answer my question.

Comment: @JensGustedt looks like a homework.

Comment: Good case for using [Sqlite](http://sqlite.org/)

Answer (score 0):

This is the function I have written so far. This function is called repeatedly after fetching each line in the main() function using fgets(). Inputs to the function are the line read from fgets() and the two column numbers that need to be swapped.
In Below code Matrix is a of the type char *** declared globally.

```
char ** switch_column(const char * str, int col1, int col2)
{
int count =0, str_length =0;
const char delimiters[] = " \t";
char *token;
char * tmp = strdup(str);
int nLineChar_count =0;
int mat_indx;
char *place_holder;
tok_count =0;
Matrix[curr_line -1] = (char **)malloc(MAX_LINE_LENGTH*sizeof(char*));
str_length = strlen(str);

printf("%d\n",str_length);

token = strtok(tmp,delimiters); // Get first Token from the str
Matrix[curr_line -1][0] = token;
mat_indx =1;
tok_count++;
while(token || token != NULL)
{
    token = strtok(NULL,delimiters); // Get all other tokens following the first in str
    Matrix[curr_line -1][mat_indx++] = token;

    printf("%s\n",token);
    tok_count++;
}


if(Matrix[curr_line -1][col1-1] != NULL && Matrix[curr_line -1][col2-1] != NULL)
{
    place_holder = Matrix[curr_line -1][col1-1];
    Matrix[curr_line -1][col1-1] = Matrix[curr_line -1][col2-1];
    Matrix[curr_line -1][col2-1] = place_holder;
}

return Matrix[curr_line -1];
}
```